# Trying to use an object in another class's header file, getting "redefinition of class" error

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, header-files, redefinition

I am currently trying to define a class "School" in a School.hpp file. Part of the School class is a vector of Student objects called roster. If I #include "Student.hpp" in School.hpp, the compiler throws "a redefinition of ‘class Student’" error. If I don't include Student.hpp, it throws a "'Student' was not declared in this scope" error for std::vector< Student>.

I don't know where it thinks I'm redefining the Student class as I only have the class definition for Student once, and that's in the Student.hpp file.

```
// School.hpp
#include <vector>
#include "Student.hpp"

class School
{
    // instance variables
    std::vector<Student> roster;
```

I'm new to C++ and working through some old school projects so apologies if this is a dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: I'm guessing that "Student.hpp" is getting included multiple times. Try adding `#pragma once` at the top of the .hpp files.

Comment: Or, if you want an approach that is supported by the C++ standard, use include guards.   `#pragma once` is considered, by some, as a "defacto standard" and is supported by most modern compilers, but is not actually supported by standard C++.   Advocates of `#pragma once` tend to point out the advantages (yes, there are plenty), but pretend there are no disadvantages (of which there are several too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did not tell the preprocessor that the header file must be included once.

On top of each header file ('*.hpp'), add this line:

```cpp
#pragma once
```

For more info, see [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)